# How to check if callback exists in props in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have this component that has these props:

```
export type Props = NavigationScreenProps & {

    name: string
    testCallback?: () => void

}
```

How do I check if this callback exists and then call the callback?

Comment: `props.testCallback && props.testCallback()`

Comment: Also `props?.testCallback()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
const {testCallback = null} = props || {}

if(testCallback){
testCallback()
}
```